# Landscape/Portrait conflict - iOS

Tags: iphone, interface, ios, orientation, device

Just when i thought I had everything figured out .. i got this problem.

the scenario.

I got a simple tableView. and with a search bar in  navigation item's titleView. The SearchBar is  added to navItems titleView via a uibarbuttonitem in view controllers toolbar.

NOW, normally

After initiating the searchbar with [beginResponder] the keyboard shows up. And It sends out a notification "KeyboardDidShow" which is where i calculate the UIKeyboard's height and set the tableView's height accordingly (Shorten it).

ON Rotation - to and fro landscape/portrait, everything works fine. 
-(void)didRotateInferfaceOrientation is called and everythings kool.

Heres the problem.

When the keyboard is active, it has a Google "search" button, this pushes to a new view - webviewcontroller.

the problem is, this

When, [PORTRAIT]ViewController [SearchBar with keyboard active] --> taps Search --> [Portrait]WebViewController --> Change Device Orientation to [Landscape] --> [Landscape]WebViewController changes to landscape ---> HERES THE PROBLEM, user taps back to uiViewController[Landscape]

the method -didRotatefromInterfaceOrientation isnt called. and somehow the tableView height is messed up. Though the view is rotating perfectly.

Is there something im missing here..

would appreciate any help. .thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a similar problem in one of my applications recently, not exactly our problem but don't bother, you should see what I'm heading for: I wanted to simply rotate an viewController displayed using presentModalViewController...Unfortunatly it didn't really worked put, especially on old iPhone with OS prior to iOS 4...So I needed to rotate programatically! Just get your screen size, use CGAffineTransform or something like that and change the sizes and then you should be done...
If your interested I could post a bunch of code, so let me know!

EDIT:

```
UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
        myController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, screen.bounds.size.height, screen.bounds.size.width - 20);
        if(currentOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
            myController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(myController.view.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(-90)));

        }else{
            myController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(myController.view.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90)));

        }
        myController.view.center = window.center;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:currentOrientation];
        [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
        [self.window bringSubviewToFront:self.tabBarController.view];
        [self.window addSubview:myController.view];
        [self.window bringSubviewToFront:myController.view];
        [self.tabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];`
```

This also includes removing a TabBar when rotating to landscape to get some more space...enjoy :)

Comment: I would definitely be interested if you can throw some code there :)

Comment: I edited my previous post, so just take a look at it and tell me if it fits your needs, otherwise I can suggest something other :D

Answer (score 1):

When user taps back, -didRotatefromInterfaceOrientation will not be called. You need to check orientation in viewWillAppear (or call viewDidLoad, prior to returning from tap on back), and then call the proper layout for the chosen orientation.

In all of your (BOOL)shouldRotate... methods, you should be call a separate method to ensure your layout is correct for the device orientation.

Comment: You mean have a single method for Orientation purposes, then call it everytime on ViewDidLoad and viewWillAppear ??

Comment: Have a single method for orientation purposes and call it everytime -BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation is called.

Answer (score 0):

You could call didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation manually on viewWillAppear and just pass an orientation yourself (i.e. [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation).